# how can I add onclick by for loop, for mr[2] and test1[2]

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, onclick

how can I add `onclick` by for loop, for `mr[2]` and `test1[2]`

I have more buttons and iframes

```
mr[2].onclick = function selectItem() {
    for (var i = 0; i < mr.length; i++) {
        mr[i].classList.remove('selected');
        mr[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(21,21,21,1)';
    };

    this.classList.add('selected');
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff5722';

    for (var i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {
        test1[i].setAttribute('src', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Olive_green_check.svg');
        test1[i].style.display = 'none';
    };

    test1[2].setAttribute('src', 'www.google.com');
    test1[2].style.display = 'block';
};
```

Comment: What are `mr[2]` and `test1[2]`?

Comment: What's the problem with what you've written?

Answer (score 1):

Consider maybe simply use the DOM Element method addEventListener  on the obejcts you want to add the "onclick" property to as a possible solution:

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 0):

mr[2] is button 2 from 5 buttons and test1[2] is iframe 2 from 5 iframes